Specializing template method for a template class in C++
I have a following class:
struct RecipeParser
{
public:
    RecipeParser(const std::string &filepath_);

private:
    template <typename T>
    TimelineProperty<T> parseTimelineProperty(nlohmann::json &json_);

    template <typename T>
    Vector2<T> parseVector2(const nlohmann::json &json_);
};

I want to specialize parseTimelineProperty method for a Vector2<T> so that it would use parseVector2<T> method. However, if I add a method with this prototype:
template <typename T>
TimelineProperty<Vector2<T>> parseTimelineProperty(nlohmann::json &json_);

and try to call it with parseTimelineProperty<Vector2<float>>(data), I get a compiler error "more than one instance of overloaded function "RecipeParser::parseTimelineProperty" matches the argument list". Is it possible to specialize method for Vector2<T> or do I have to add a new method with a different name?
EDIT. I have just realized that I am passing Vector2<float> as template parameter and even if it was a separate method, I would call a parseTimelineProperty<Vector2<Vector2<float>>> version. The question remains the same

This shown code is not a template specification, this an overlord.

You can't overload on return type alone.
